# State not fetching API data on submit

Tags: reactjs, api

First stackoverflow post. New to React (1 week) and using API fetch requests to understand props, state and components.

I'm using a weather API to get the temperature for a particular city. User enters city into a form, clicks submit and the temperature is displayed.

When I hard code the selectedCity state by typing in a city as a test, I can see in the DevTools that the API data is fetched for that city and the city's temperature is displayed in the browser. The issue is when I click submit on my form component. On submit I can see in the DevTools that it updates the selectedCity state with user's city of choice but it doesn't fetch the data. I've noticed that when hard coding in the city that the page refreshes and the data is fetched and result displayed but when submitted via the form there is no refresh of the page.

I just don't know enough about React to figure out what is going on here. Grateful for any pointers.

This is my WeatherContainer

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Headings from '../components/Headings';
import Form from '../components/Form';
import Weather from '../components/Weather';


class WeatherContainer extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { 
            weatherData: [],
            selectedCity: ""     
        };
        this.handleFormSubmit = this.handleFormSubmit.bind(this);
    }

    fetchData() {
            fetch(`https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=${this.state.selectedCity}&APPID=MyAPIKey`)
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then(result => this.setState({ weatherData: result.main }))            
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.fetchData();
    }

    handleFormSubmit({city}) {
        this.setState({selectedCity: city})
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <Headings />
                <Form onFormSubmit={this.handleFormSubmit} />
                <Weather weather={this.state.weatherData} />
            </div>  
        );
    }
}

export default WeatherContainer;
```

This is my form component

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class Form extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { 
            city: ""
        };
        this.handleCityChange = this.handleCityChange.bind(this);
        this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
    }

    handleSubmit(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        const city = this.state.city;
        if (!city) {
            return
        }

        this.props.onFormSubmit({
            city: city
        });

        this.setState({
            city: ''
        })
    }

    handleCityChange(event) {
        this.setState({
            city: event.target.value
        })
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                <input
                    type="text"
                    value={this.state.city}
                    placeholder="Enter City"
                    onChange={this.handleCityChange}
                />
               <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
                {/* <button>Get Weather</button> */}
            </form>
        );
    }
}

export default Form;
```

My Weather Component

```
import React from 'react';

const Weather = ({ weather }) => {
    if(!weather) return null

    return (
        <div>
            <h1>{weather.temp}</h1>
        </div>
    );
} 

export default Weather;
```

Comment: did my answer help you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you have a `componentDidMount` method but you don't handle the updates of the state.
You need a `componentDidUpdate` method

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
  if (prevState.city !== this.state.city) {
    this.fetchData();
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the help. All i did was change my componentDidMount to componentDidUpdate and it worked straight away. Don't think I would have figured that one out without your help.

Comment: ok great, please accept my answer for this question to be considered "answered". thank you and welcome to stackoverflow!